# How to change date format to custom in Views? (drupal 6, views2)

Tags: views, 6, entities

I have a view that includes a CCK date/time field. It automatically displays the date like this if I choose Long as the format:

Tuesday, April 17, 2012 - 13:30

I need it to display in 12-hour time, not 24-hour, but the view field config doesn't allow me to enter a custom format for my date (for the label, yes - the actual value, no). How can I override the date formatting for just this one view?

[image]

**EDIT**

Never mind; I found a way to do it [here](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/how-create-custom-date-format-better-theming-drupal-views).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found [here](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/how-create-custom-date-format-better-theming-drupal-views). Basically, you create a new date format in admin that is then available sitewide in any date format dropdown.